# Array.map() versus for loop when title-casing a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, array.prototype.map

I was working on a FreeCodeCamp algorithm problem where I was asked to title-case a given string, as in to make the first letter of every word capitalized. I managed to do so using this code:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var wordArr = str.split(" ");
  for(var i=0; i<wordArr.length; i++){
    wordArr[i] = wordArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + wordArr[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
  }
  return wordArr.join(" ");

}
```

But I started by trying to use array.map() in a manner like this:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var wordArr = str.split(" ");
  var newArr = wordArr.map(function(word){
    word = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  });
  return newArr;

}
```

I didn't even bother trying to concatenate (i.e. with `.join()`) the array because it was an array of *null* values. Why didn't `array.map()` work in this situation? Or did I just make a stupid mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.map` accepts a function which takes an original value and should **return** a projected value.
Your function returns nothing, it just reassigns `word` value which doesn't affect anything since `word` is a local variable.

This is the correct usage of `map` function:

```
var wordArr = str.split(" ");
var newArr = wordArr.map(function(word){
  return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
});
return newArr;
```

Demo:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.split(" ").map(function(word){
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}

console.log(titleCase("hello") + " " + titleCase("world") + "!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return inside the map function

Sample code:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var wordArr = str.split(" ");
  var newArr = wordArr.map(function(word){
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  });
  return newArr.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why didn't `array.map()` work in this situation?

Per the MDN documentation for [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array with the **results** of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

Implied in that statement, .map() needs the **results** from each call, and for that use the [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) keyword to send the value back for each iteration. Otherwise the value (i.e. assigned to `word`) is unused (outside of the callback function). See this demonstrated in the code below.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.split(" ").map(function(word){
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}

console.log(titleCase("title case this string"));
```

P.S. if you would like to learn more about functional Programming in Javascript, I recommend going through the exercises on [this page](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/).